# Embedd Images from MongoDB gridFS into my HTML-Page

Tags: html, mongodb, image, gridfs

I saved some files via MongoDBs gridFS into my database.
I know how to retrieve files just with php in my browser:

```
header('Content-type: '.$object->file['filetype']);
echo $object->getBytes();
```

That works perfectly fine. But I now wan't to put the image in a context.

e.g.

```
<img><?php echo $object->getBytes(); ?></img>
```

If I put the code

```
echo $object->getBytes();
```

in a htmlpage, I just get the image like this:

> ����JFIFHH��C !"$"$��C���Y"�� ��O!"12AQaq�BR��#b��3Cr��$S����4���%cs�5&��DT�������&!1A"Q2q�#Ba��?�( �#�EUDDUU�#��(�?2� ��.h#k���.��d�M���(��=�]��Nk��E�gZz�GI�Вr��*�~+x������<{YZSm�n�N I�DAmDU��*����G���U:���H�6J̺'!lV�������D:H2��S��7��U;����7����������n��wV$�ʞ�i|��wP����?Qx۾�/�K'�:=���i�E�0)�E��4OU�G�W��`t] �������.�j��='�/�:9�V����봺a_}2����a_�D��J[r�J���*f�6�B<���ѿc���=8�Q��1!("��B���⅝4<#��L���K�Iy*�"���?�6�6�a7�k����%�F6�y��� v��

and so on...

does anybody know how I can embedd an image into a website???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new PHP page that returns the image (with appropriate content-type and content-length headers) like your first sample above. Say that page is called "image.php". In your "main" page, then, you should construct an image tag like:

```
<img src="/path/to/image.php?..."/>
```

Where "..." is replaced with some query string to look up and serve the image you want (the string representation of the GridFS file's ObjectId in the `_id` field might do well here, or some other unique identifier).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for in-doc images you could try

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,����JFIFHH��C !"$"$��C���Y..." />`

But dcrosta's method may be preferred depending on your overall intent.

You'll have to plug in the correct image type and encoding (or re-encode).